# Sierpinski number analogue in another base

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was wondering if [Sierpinski numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number) would work in other bases, and after a little experimentation: yep!

For instance,

$$157 \cdot 23^n - 2$$

is composite for all $n$ using a tiny covering set. Or,

$$5515 \cdot 11^n + 2.$$

If I'm mistaken, please let me know.

Comment: This is interesting (+1).  How did you find these?

Comment: Picked bases likely to be neutral relative to the numbers that usually make up these covering sets (3,5,7,13,17,19,37,73,etc), and then quick brute force check for a coefficient which seemed to hit those 0-congruences.

Comment: Note that these differ from classic Sierpinski numbers not only in the base not being $2$ but also the added constant isn’t $1$

Comment: Cf. [Riesel number base $b$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesel_number#Riesel_number_base_b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$157\times23^{2k+1}-2\equiv1\times2-2=0\bmod 3$,

$157\times23^{4k+2}-2\equiv(-2)(-1)-2=0\bmod53$,

and $157\times23^{4k}-2\equiv2\times1-2=0\bmod5$,

so $157\times23^n-2$ is composite for all $n$.

$5515\times11^{3k+1}+2\equiv5\times11+2\equiv0\bmod 19$,

$5515\times11^{3k+2}+2\equiv6\times16+2\equiv0\bmod7$,

$5515\times11^{2k}+2\equiv1\times1+2\equiv0\bmod3,$

and $5515\times11^{6k+3}+2\equiv2\times(-1)+2\equiv0\bmod37$,

so $5515\times11^n+2$ is composite for all $n$.